# Watch Vuex state computed property in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, watch

I'm trying to make a watcher for a computed property which uses `mapState` to get the a `vuex` state:

```js
computed: {
    ...mapState({
        sheetEdit: 'sheetEdit',
    }),
},

watch: {
    sheetEdit() {
        //do something
    },
```

Now the problem is that the watcher is never triggered despite changes happen in the `sheetEdit` in Vuex. What is the correct way to watch for changes in this case?

Thanks

### UPDATE

In Vuex, this is how I'm updating the state:

```js
export const state = () => ({
    editSheet: [],
)}

export const mutations = {
    SET_EDITSHEET(state, edits) {
        state.editSheet.push(edits)
    },
    DELETE_EDITSHEET(state, edits) {
        const index = state.ediSheet.indexOf(edits)
        if (index > -1){
            state.editSheet.splice(index, 1)
        }
    },
}

export const actions = {
    setSheetEdits({ commit }, edits) {
        commit('SET_EDITSHEET', edits)
    },
    deleteSheetEdits({ commit }, edits) {
        commit('DELETE_EDITSHEET', edits)
    },
}
```

Comment: Your state is called `editSheet` but you're mapping `sheetEdit`.  Is that a post typo or no?